# Copy table with inner table using tabletools i asp mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, css

I have a problem in my webpage i generate an table it look like this :

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">Result</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <table id="Table" class="table table-condensed display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var table in Model.Table)
                {
                    <th>@table.head</th>
                }
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

Then i generate whole table ( part of code )

```
element.dataTable({
            dom: '<"dataTables-header"Tf>tr<"dataTables-footer"Si>',
            data: data,
            deferRender: true,
            autoWidth: true,
            scrollX: '100%',
            scrollY: '350px',
            processing: false,
            scrollCollapse: false,
            tableTools: {
                'aButtons': [
                    {
                        'sExtends': 'copy',
                        "oSelectorOpts": 
                        {
                            "filter": "applied" ,

                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        'sExtends': 'xls',
                        'sFileName': '*.xls',
                        "oSelectorOpts": 
                        {
                            "filter": "applied" 
                        }
                    }
                ],
                sSwfPath: "../Content/DataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
            },
            columns: [
                @foreach (var table in Model.Table)
                {
                    <text>{ data: '@table.data' },</text>
                }
            ]
        });
```

and then add some inner table :

```
        function format(item) {
            var innerTable = '<div style="font-size: 14px;">' +
                 '<div class="col-sm-3">' +
                 '<H4 align="right" style="padding-right:2em;">Inner</H4>' +
                 '</div>' +
                 '<div class="col-sm-9">' +
                    '<table cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table">' +
                        '<thead>' +
                            '<tr>' +
                                '<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>' +
                                '<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>' +
                                '<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>' +
                                '<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>' +
                                '<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>' +
                                '<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>' +
                                '<td><strong>Name#:</strong></td>' +
                            '</tr>' +
                        '</thead>' +
                    '<tbody>';

            for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                var it= item[i];
                innerTable += '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + it.data1 + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + it.data2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + it.data2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + it.data2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + it.data2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + it.data2 + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + it.data2 + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>';
            }

            innerTable +=
                '</tbody>' +
                '</table>' +
                '</div>' + 
                '</div>';
            return innerTable;
```

Sorry I can't show more code i hope it will be enough to understand what i need.
Now when i hit the copy or excel button i get only result only for main table ( without inner ) is there any possible to copy it all ?